# How to store ImagePath in Mysql Database?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to store an image path in my mysql database but it does not store the backslash(/).

this is my path  - `string str = @"C:\Users\user\Downloads\99 Most Amazing Collection of Computer Desktop Wallpapers - 5522 [ECLiPSE]"`

this is how it appears in mysql - C:UsersuserDownloads99 Most Amazing Collection of Computer Desktop Wallpapers - 5522 [ECLiPSE]

Because of this i am unable to retrive the image, so how do i store the imagepath with the backslash included.

**Mysql Code**

```
      string sqlstring = "server=; port= ; user id =;Password=;Database=;";

   string str = @"C:\Users\user\Downloads\99 Most Amazing Collection of 
       Computer Desktop Wallpapers - 5522 [ECLiPSE]"
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sqlstring);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            string Query = "INSERT INTO test.blogimagestable (ImagesId)values('" + str + "');";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: How are you storing your path? Can you show us your code where you are saving the path string

Comment: @RahulSharma ok

Comment: @RahulSharma i edited the question.

Comment: Stop trying to assemble SQL using string concatenation and [use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/). That will fix your current problem, and many future problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use parametrized queries to prevent such problems from happen automatically. And other nasty things, like SQL injections.

And you should rather call `ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `ExecuteReader()` for a statement, that doesn't return a result. Or at least take care of calling `Dispose()` on the useless reader or using `using`. (Same goes for your other disposable objects.)

```
...
string Query = "INSERT INTO test.blogimagestable (ImagesId)values(?str);";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("?str", MySqlDbType.VarString, 256).Value = str;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
...
```

Change the type and length passed to `Parameters.Add()` according to the type of your column.

Comment: He probably shouldn't be using `throw ex` either. @lois, please read a SQL tutorial.

Comment: @DourHighArch,i think thats my problem i should read more on sql,thanks